# Install Windows 7 onto bootcamp partition from VHD image

Tags: boot-camp, vhd

This question has been asked once before but afaik no definitive answer has been forthcoming.
Basically I have a .vhd image that was created using windows7 tools from an existing bootcamp partition. I had to reinstall MAC OsX and re-create the bootcamp partition. So far, so good.
Now the problem is to reinstall windows from the VHD. Others have booted to a windows7 install CD and then tried to use the restore system image capability. But this doesn't work: the restore writes over the entire HDD.

One proposed solution was to use (on OSX) qemu-img to convert the .vhd to a raw image and then use dd
to copy the raw image to the bootcamp partition. I have not tried it, but I know that will not work. if you look at the raw image, it contains an MBR in the first sector, and 127 empty sectors, then finally the boot sector. But a more orthodox install of windows7 onto a bootcamp partition begins with the boot sector.

Can those 128 sectors be omitted? I don't see how without making other edits to the raw image.

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this qemu method, and it did not work. I had this same task but never was able to solve it, qemu or otherwise. The problem with qemu was that it left me a partition that was not recognized as a Windows partition by the Bootcamp loader on power up. Something was missing in some partition table by just doing a raw byte copy. So, you can try the qemu method, but it didn't solve anything for me.

I ended up using Windows backup to restore my data and apps.